# Missing Ruby File in Rubygem when using Makefiles to install dependencies in Ubuntu (WSL)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux, miniconda

So I am trying to run this program from git: https://github.com/StreetScienceCommunity/DNAnalyzer

I tried to run it with my Ubuntu (WSL), then I got an old lock-file issue:
[image]

I tried to solve this problem, so I reinstalled npm by "install npm", then the old lock-file issue is gone, but now I have an issue with missing ruby file under the rubygem/bin.
[image]

The above situation occurred by simply following the instructions in git, meaning I only did "git clone" and "make create-env" (which was successful). I also tried manually activating the environment, then I got this:
[image]

I am rather new to using these...really confused about what is going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post images to StackOverflow (except for issues that are related to GUI).  Please cut and paste the text into the question, with proper formatting so it's treated as a code block.  Cheers!

Comment: Please replace fuzzy pictures of text with actual text

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest to have a read on [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)s as that will increases the change you get a useful answer.